# How to insert non null value into many to many table

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have many-to-many oracle db model between tables `A` and `B`. In db model there is common table, let's say `A_B` with fields `id` (primary key not null), `a_id` (foreign key to table A) and `b_id` (foreign key to table B).

Model in Java is like:

```
@Table(name = "A")
public class A
{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long aId;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", nullable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false) }
    )
    private List<B> b;
}

@Entity(name = "B")
public class B
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long bId;
}
```

When inserting entity A I'm receiving an error:
`cannot insert NULL into ("A_B"."ID")`.

I suppose that hibernate can not see this additional `id` as primary key in tabe `A_B`. What can I do?

I know that I can remove unnecessary `id` or set something default. But is there any way to avoid database model changes? Can I somehow implement it using only Hibernate and JPA?

Comment: A little bit off your question, but why do you need column "ID" in table "A_B"?

Comment: Seems like things are happening out of order. You cannot insert into `A_B` until referential data exists in both `A` and `B`. The insert to the join table must come last, and must include both valid `A_ID` and `B_ID`.